# Links being acted on -- style in CSS or using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, styling

Should you use a:hover, a:active, a:visited and a:link, or similar javascript things (tags??) instead?

Comment: doing it with CSS is simple and sane, I'd do it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly dependent on what you're trying to do. If a:active/:visited/:link/:hover provide sufficient styling control, use those as they work across browsers with or without JavaScript enabled. If you're trying to do something fancy that can't be accomplished with CSS, then use JavaScript. It's also common to mix the two techniques... Use CSS for the parts where you can and use JavaScript for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS when you can (in your example, there is a simple way to do what you need in CSS so that makes it a good fit).

Otherwise, fall back to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If a:active, etc. will meet your needs, I would definitely use those in your CSS. I do all the time. Did you want additional functionality?